# My tamed wolves keep killing my friend multiple times!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I play minecraft, and I tamed some wolves and bred them. My friend ambushed me and killed me. All of my dogs were sitting, but now whenever he respawns, they kill him. They've killed my friend 10 times and they still want to kill him! Now I can't go hunting with him and my dogs or else they'll try to kill him, but I've got them all sitting now. What's going on? How do I stop the dogs from doing this without cheats? Will they just keep trying to kill my friend indefinitely? Please help me!

Comment: I'm not sure if their behaviour will reset whenver put to sit or if you punch / get hurt by someone else. I'll make some research.

Comment: I don't think they would stop. The will attack skeletons and any mob or player that attacks the owner. The might also attack mobs that you hit (they did that in PE and I was on creative).

Comment: "My friend ambushed me and killed me" — Never forgive! Never forget! Woof!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the game rule `forgiveDeadPlayers` is set to `false`. Try changing it to `true`, then your wolves should stop attacking your friend when he respawns.

Edit: Nevermind, that game rule didn't exist back then. If you didn't update to 1.16, there's nothing you can do about angered mobs ignoring death and respawn. 1.15 and earlier just does that.

Comment: regardless this is a good answer

Answer (score 1):

You can stop this from happening by having your friend **relog**. Aka get them to get off then back on. Then don't have your friend harm your Minecraft character.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but since wolves act like Zombie Pigmen they might have a cooldown so let them sit tell your friend to feed them, i had the same situation 2 years ago

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior for a dog. Dog's attack the player/mob if the player or mob attacks. The dog's will go and kill the mob/player since it hurt the trainer/owner. They will also attack mobs or players they hurt. So if you have attacked you're friend, or he attacked you, That is why.

Answer (score -2):

That happened to me before. I don't know if it works but maybe your friend could feed the wolves beef. It might work.